# Disadvantage of using mutex in interrupt context

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

What is Disadvantage of using mutex in interrupt context.Why spin lock is preferred here.

Comment: Locking mutex is prohibited within interrupt context. The reason is same as one for semaphores and is described [in the first related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464700/why-spinlocks-are-used-in-interrupt-handlers).

Comment: A spin lock is a form of mutex.

Answer (score 1):

A Mutex will force the function to sleep if it's contended and sleeping is illegal when preemption is disabled or in interrupt context.

> Many functions in the kernel sleep (ie. call schedule()) directly or
>   indirectly: you can never call them while holding a spinlock, or with
>   preemption disabled. This also means you need to be in user context:
>   calling them from an interrupt is illegal.

The following is worth reading...

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/c557.html

Theres a ton of information in that doc.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread tries to acquire a `mutex` and if it does not succeed, either due to another thread having already acquired it or due to a context switch, the thread goes to sleep until been woken-up which is critical if used in an ISR.

Whereas when a thread fails to acquire a `spin_lock`, it continuously tries to acquire it, until it finally succeeds, thus avoiding sleeping in an ISR. Using `spin_lock` in the "top-half" is a common practice followed in writing Linux Device Driver Interrupt handlers.

Hence you should use a spin-lock instead!